# Persisting value objects in Typo3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I've got a `Money` class that extends `AbstractValueObject` with the properties `$amount` (int) and `$currency` (string). And I've got an `AbstractEntity` with a `$price` property holding an instance of `Money`. How do I get Typo3 to persist that value object? How do I define the mapping?

Coming from Doctrine, I'd expect it to be persisted in two columns `price_amount` and `price_currency`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extbase does things a bit differently - so [value objects](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html#use-inheritance-in-class-hierarchies) needs to be stored in their own tables and relations between objects are stored by using identifiers just like entities.
The only real difference between Entities and VOs is that the persistence manager  will use `property values` (except the identifier field) when looking for VOs for persistence whereas the `identifier` will be used on Entities.

- So you need to add the [database schema](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html) for the value object to `ext_tables.sql` and as the table should contain an auto incrementing `uid` field as well as the fields you need for your VO. Ensure that you create a combined unique index on the `amount` and `currency` columns.
- Define the TCA mapping and then you can persist value objects either directly if you create a repository or by attaching them to aggregate root objects and persisting these.

The `price` property on your entity should be an integer in the database schema, as extbase will either store a reference to the uid of the VO (if you only refer to one Money object on your entity) and if you wish to store a [collection](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group.html#mm) of Money objects, Extbase will store the number of relations between your entity object and the Money VOs.

Comment: That's _exactly_ the information I was looking for. I think it's kind of a weird implementation, but at least I know what to do now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome and I agree with you about the strange way it's implemented. However due to the integration of Doctrine in TYPO3 8LTS and the continued work on getting TYPO3 to be more standards compliant, one could hope that the implementation will change in a future major release.